# Installing Ubuntu on a desktop that was built from scratch

Tags: system-installation, hardware

After having some problems with an old desktop (not a laptop), I decided to fix it for good. I've changed the motherboard (the old one kept failing), RAM, cooler, etc. Now the desktop has the following specs: 8gb of RAM, i5 processor, 1tb HD. All in all, it's a pretty decent computer. However, after changing the motherboard, I lost my windows 10 license. I don't really care about W10, so this gave me the opportunity to clean out my HD and remove W10.

All this to  say that now I have a PC without an OS. I'd like to install the latest Ubuntu version on it, but I don't know if it's compatible. I know that Ubuntu's website has a list for hardware compatibility, but that's mostly for laptops and desktops that have been built by a company and never been altered. My desktop is just a bunch of parts from different brands.

So my question is: is Ubuntu gonna work on it? I know that's too broad, and there isn't an exact way of knowing. But if anyone has done something similar in the past, I'd appreciate some insight. I mean, even if I install and it runs fine, will I have incompatibility issues in the future such as not being able to use all my 8gb of RAM, or just the PC suddenly not working?

Another question that popped in my head: if Ubuntu is not the best OS for a desktop that has been assembled from scratch, which Linux distro (Linux Mint, CentOS, etc.) would be best (has the highest chance of compatibility)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I use Ubuntu for more than 5 years. During this period I quite a lot did move my disk drive (nowdays it is an SSD storage) to other machines (PC) with various hardware config and never had any problem booting or running Ubuntu OS.

As @user535733 mentioned, You could try Live version, but I am 99% sure You will install Ubuntu and won't be let down.

Answer (score 2):

I've run Ubuntu on various assembled systems for a decade: Desktops, laptops, servers, Rpis, etc.

The easy way to find out is to make and Ubuntu LiveUSB...boot from it and try it out. The LiveUSB has a "Try Ubuntu" environment specifically so you can see how it runs on your hardware before committing to an install.

- No Windows means no Product Key to protect, so no commitment anyway.
- Ubuntu works on a broad variety of hardware.
- Hardware that is newly released on the market may (or may not) encounter issues with older releases of Ubuntu.

Advice: Stick to the installer defaults first time so you KNOW it works. You can always reinstall with another configuration anytime.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out would be to create a Live USB using Rufus or some another tool.Use try Ubuntu option.It will not take long.

If the OS works as I believe it should,you can then choose whatever distro you want.Most of them should be compatible and all have their quirks.Choose whatever suits you.I would suggest you go for Ubuntu first if you are trying Linux for first time and then  go for others as you become more familiar.